# Determine which UIViewController runs first

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, viewcontroller

I started to learn objective-c and ios programming.I have two View Controller which are named MainViewController and GameViewController,also there are two xib files in my project.I connected xib files with the ViewController's.Totally Here are my files:

View Controllers,

```
    AppDelegate.h
    AppDelegate.m
    MainViewController.h
    MainViewController.m
    GameViewController.h
    GameViewController.m
```

and xibs,

```
    Main.xib
    Game.xib
```

I choose Main.xib as main interface in the project options.I'm trying to understand questions below,when i run this application first main.m runs.Thats okay.

After that does the AppDelegate class runs?How xcode determines which View Controller will run first?

With this project when i run,there is only black screen.Can anyone help me about an ios application's run order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode doesn't determine anything, it's entirely up to you to set up your UI after

```
-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions
```

is called by the system.  Below is an example where `ExampleViewController` is initialized first:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The Application initialization flow is:

```
main() -> AppDelegate (or whatever class has been designated the delegate) -> initial view controller
```

Comment: In this example you need to import CRViewController.Am i right?

Comment: This is pseudo-code, but yes.  Your application is blank because you aren't initializing a view controller.

Comment: what does that if determines? 
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

Comment: i wrote ur advice but there is an error,Property viewController not found on object type of 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: You can't just copy pseudo-code verbatim... Define this in your .H: @property (strong, nonatomic) ExampleViewController *viewController;

Comment: is this correct? @property (strong,nonatomic)UIViewController *viewController;

Comment: @Gandalf Yes.  Obviously you'll need to replace the names of the example classes with some of your own.

Comment: i got a run-time error this time,loaded the "Main" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: @Gandalf The error is really quite explicit: Go into your XIB, and drag the view outlet to the view you set up on the canvas.  Voila!

Comment: @programmer i checked your answer,but what i meant is not that,i want set the first view controller,which appears when application runs

Comment: @Gandalf check out the new answer :)

Comment: @CodaFi i really thank you for your answers to my beginner questions,and your time :)